# C API use to connect C & SQL database

Tags: mysql, c, database, c-api

I am trying to use C API to connect my C code to my SQL. I was wondering if anyone has any good beginner  resources so I can get up to speed. All I am trying to do is just store data in tables I made in SQL. If it helps I am using MySQL on my Mac. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. This sort of question tends to get closed as 'too broad', or other reasons.  Generally, questions work best when you can show some code and ask what is wrong with it, assuming you've made an honest attempt to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a good MySQL tutorial here: [MySQL C API programming tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/)

Here is the official documentation:

1. [20.6.6 C API Function Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-function-overview.html)
2. [20.6.3 Example C API Client Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-example-programs.html)

Answer (score 0):

The link below has some simple example how to use C API to interact with MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html

Comment: Please try and link to the current version of the documentation (e.g. 5.6).